# How to edit the deafult value of combobox in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need your help.
I am trying to change the default value of combobox in a function of javascript.

It should be when I click on the radio button. The call to the function of the radio button is ok, but I didn`t succeed to change the default value of the combobox.

```js
 function contractRoleClick(option)
    {
    var assetsComboBox = document.getElementById("sellersAssetsCombobox");
            assetsComboBox.disabled = true; //irrelevant
            
            if (option.value == 2)
            {
               document.getElementById('sellersAssetsCombobox').option[0].value = "bbb"; //not working

                document.getElementById("sellersAssetsCombobox").selectedIndex = 0; //the only line that work, but I don`t need it!
                document.getElementById("sellersAssetsCombobox").options[0] = "aaa"; //not working
                document.getElementById("sellersAssetsCombobox").options.item(0).text = "asd"; //not working
            }
        }
```

```html
    <select class="custom-select" disabled id="sellersAssetsCombobox" onchange="getAssetDetails(this)">
                                        <option value="0" selected="" >Open this to select Seller`s assets</option> <!--I want to change this value-->
                                        <option value="1">Code: 15524  ->  Value: 366 ETH</option>
                                        <option value="2">Code: 74121  ->  Value: 841 ETH</option>
                                        <option value="3">Code: 66473  ->  Value: 510 ETH</option>
                                    </select>
```

When I click on the radio button, the function should change the deafult value "Open this to select Seller`s assets" to a new value: "Open this to select your assets", and reset any previous selected value to the new value. The reset to deaflut index worked, but I need to change it as I mentioned before.

Any help will be appreciated!

Haim

Comment: I want only to change one value. The first value that been showed up before I pick any other value in the combobox. That's it.

Comment: Please look here; https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501914713745

Comment: document.getElementById("sellersAssetsCombobox").options[0].value = "1"; --->NOT WORKING

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
function contractRoleClick(option)
    {
        var assetsComboBox = document.getElementById("sellersAssetsCombobox");
        assetsComboBox.disabled = true;
        //Open this to select Seller`s assets
        if (option.value == 2) {

            var myComboBox = document.getElementById('sellersAssetsCombobox');
            var optionCombo = document.createElement("option");

            myComboBox.remove(0);
            optionCombo.text = "Open this to select your asset";
            myComboBox.add(optionCombo,0);
            myComboBox.selectedIndex = 0;

        }
    }
```

Thx anyway.
Haim

Comment: What I did is to delete the previous value in index 0, add a new value at the last index, move the new value to the first index (=0). AND IT`S WORKED!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default (selected?) value of a combo box just set its .value. You shouldn't need to move around the options.

If you want to change the text of the option use .innerHTML

```js
function contractRoleClick(option) {
  document.getElementById("sellersAssetsCombobox").value = option;
}
function changeTextOfSelected() {
  document.getElementById('sellersAssetsCombobox').options[
    document.getElementById('sellersAssetsCombobox').selectedIndex
  ].innerHTML = 'Changed this ' + Math.random()
}
btn1.addEventListener('click', () => contractRoleClick(1));
btn2.addEventListener('click', () => contractRoleClick(2));
btn3.addEventListener('click', () => {
  contractRoleClick(3); changeTextOfSelected();
});
```

```html
<select class="custom-select" id="sellersAssetsCombobox" onchange="getAssetDetails(this)">
  <option value="0" selected="" >Open this to select Seller`s assets</option> <!--I want to change this value-->
  <option value="1">Code: 15524  ->  Value: 366 ETH</option>
  <option value="2">Code: 74121  ->  Value: 841 ETH</option>
  <option value="3">Code: 66473  ->  Value: 510 ETH</option>
</select>
<button id="btn1">Select 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Select 2</button>
<button id="btn3">Select and Change 3</button>
```